# Javascript export local storage

Tags: javascript, json, download, export, local-storage

I have this piece of code on a site that exports the contents of local storage to a file in JSON format.
For some reason it stopped working. I tested it in multiple browsers but it's all the same...
No errors get displayed, yet it doesn't export either.
The different variables seem fine, yet it just isn't exporting.
To be honest I have no clue how to do this differently so any help would be appreciated.

Thx

```
function exportHistory() {  
    console.log("started"); 
    var _myArray = JSON.stringify(localStorage , null, 4); //indentation in json format, human readable

    var vLink = document.getElementById('exportHistory'),
    var vBlob = new Blob([_myArray], {type: "octet/stream"}),
    vName = 'working_history_' + todayDate() + '.json',
    vUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(vBlob);
    console.log(vLink);

    vLink.setAttribute('href', vUrl);
    vLink.setAttribute('download', vName );
    console.log("finished");    
}



<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" id="exportHistory" onclick="exportHistory()">Export History</button >
```

Comment: Check if removing replacing the commas at the end of  statements with semicolons help

Comment: No luck...  Btw, when looking at the console the vLink variable contains this:
`<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" id="exportHistory" onclick="exportHistory()" href="blob:null/5545e755-87a9-4223-9df2-9d07fee06ccf" download="working_history_04-05-2020.json">Export History</button>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you need to add the `download` attribute to an anchor tag `<a>` rather than the clicking button itself. You need to create an anchor tag with `display:none` and programmatically click it to download the file. Here is an example. Notice the button only used to execute the function and `href` and `download` attributes are added to the `<a>` tag.

```
function exportHistory() {  
    console.log("started"); 
    var _myArray = JSON.stringify(localStorage , null, 4); //indentation in json format, human readable


    //Note: We use the anchor tag here instead button.
    var vLink = document.getElementById('exportHistoryLink');

    var vBlob = new Blob([_myArray], {type: "octet/stream"});
    vName = 'working_history_' + todayDate() + '.json';
    vUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(vBlob);
    console.log(vLink);

    vLink.setAttribute('href', vUrl);
    vLink.setAttribute('download', vName );

    //Note: Programmatically click the link to download the file
    vLink.click();

    console.log("finished");    
}
```

Now add an empty anchor tag to the DOM.

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" id="exportHistory" onclick="exportHistory()">Export History</button > 

<a id="exportHistoryLink" style="display: none;">Export</a>
```

Comment: This works. Do you also know why a 'ghost' link works but a button doesn't? And why it stopped working? Cause it worked before...

Comment: Maybe chrome has removed it due to some security reasons. It's worth to find out. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2011/08/Downloading-resources-in-HTML5-a-download